# On binds events many times.But I need event to be working only one time

Tags: jquery, events

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').on('click', '.pureElement', function () {
//Some Ajax call
});
```

I am hooking event to an element  as above.
On every  execution of this  event hooking code it add an event to the element.
It do not overwrite the current event.

ie If this code execute 4 times, on one click of the pureElement the Ajax call will fire 4 times.

I just need  events working only once,even if i bind event may time.
What can I do to specify the event should be fired only once?

Comment: So why are you bind it many times? Doesn't make mush sense here. Why not just using as delegate target the closest static container?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .off()

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').off('click').on('click', '.pureElement', function () {
//Some Ajax call
});
```

Comment: You could namespace it i think, just in case

Comment: This seems to be an answer

Answer (score 0):

use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').one('click', '.pureElement', function () {
 //Some Ajax call
});
```

however my doubt is `it add an event to the element. It do not overwrite the current event.` which should not happen... unless there is event bubbling... can you post more of your codes.. or related HTML

Comment: if I click second time it should fire ,the same event. But it should not fire more than one time in a single click

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').on('click', '.pureElement', function (event) {

event.stopImmediatePropagation();

//Some Ajax call
```

});

Comment: The event will be already propagated to the #fancybox-wrap's level